# How do I reference a value in one excel sheet that is in the same row as in another sheet.

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have two excel sheets, each has a column called unique ID. The first sheets has a value associated with that ID, the second has a description. How do I pull the description from sheet two into sheet one where they both have the ID in common ?

Comment: `VLOOKUP` should be the [function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) you need, which apparently you know because you used it as a tag. Have you tried using that? What didn't work? https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**How it works:**

- Write this Formula in Cell `C3` of `Sheet 1`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet2!$A$3:$B$7,2,FALSE),"No Match ID")
  ```
- **Or** you may use this Formula also:

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!B$3:B$7,(MATCH($A3,Sheet2!A$3:A$7,0))),"No Match")
  ```

**Note:**

- *Drag both formulas down.*
- *Adjust cell references in the formulas as 
  needed.*